# How to implement and configure circuit breaking in Apache APISIX?

Tags: api-gateway, apache-apisix

Circuit breaking needs to be configured in the current environment, so how to implement the circuit breaking at the gateway layer?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of circuit breaking:

```bash
curl "http://127.0.0.1:9180/apisix/admin/routes/1"  -H 'X-API-KEY: edd1c9f034335f136f87ad84b625c8f1' -X PUT -d '
{
    "uri": "/hello",
    "plugins": {
        "api-breaker": {
            "break_response_code": 502,
            "unhealthy": {
                "http_statuses": [500, 503],
            },
        }
    },
    "upstream": {
        "nodes": {
            "httpbin.org:80": 1
        }
    }
}'
```

You can read more [here](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/api-breaker/).